# Error onSaveInstanceState in android

Tags: android

I am displaying views in Android activity, which loads data through http and navigates views via thread.

It is perfectly work well. But while it's loading data and I press back then it has been crashed. My error code is as below. I have also implemented onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState().

Do needful,
Thanks.

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){     
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override 
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.sample.android/com.sample.android.SampleActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3354)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3311)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3294)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2500(ActivityThread.java:126)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2045)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4633)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onSaveInstanceState(ViewPager.java:507)
 at android.view.View.dispatchSaveInstanceState(View.java:6068)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:1180) 
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:1184)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:1184)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:1184)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:1184)
 at android.view.View.saveHierarchyState(View.java:6051) 
 at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.saveHierarchyState(PhoneWindow.java:1490)
 at android.app.Activity.onSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1086)
 at com.yoke.android.SampleActivity.onSaveInstanceState(YokeActivity.java:352)
 at android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1036)
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1180)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3336)
```

Comment: It looks like on your "back" press, Android is trying to save the view state in whichever way, but those views are not yet set up.  Try intercepting the "back" button so as not to let is do what it needs - until your layout is active.  After that, let it do what it normally would.

Comment: Hey Aleks, thanks for your response, This is first activity, which loads data, when it loads and I press back[device button], it should be exit without any error, but not.